# Why is it that setting TextInput focus equal to True, makes TextInput not respond to keyboard input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

#### **Background:**

I have a button that adds `TextInput` widgets to a `GridLayout` with `focus: True`.  If a `TextInput` is already present in the layout with `focus = True`, the previous `TextInput` is firstly unfocused then a new `TextInput` is added with `focus = True`.

#### **Problem:**

Once a `TextInput` is added I cannot type even though the cursor is focused on the added `TextInput`.
Secondary problem is when an user clicks on another widget the `TextInput` stays focused.  Meaning an unfocus event cannot be fired.

#### **Tried:**

I removed setting the focus explicitly, but then the desired result to start typing after adding a `TextInput` is lost.
Secondary I tried setting `unfocus_on_touch = True`, but the `TextInput` stayed focused even after user left the `TextInput`.

#### **Code:**

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.bubble import Bubble
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window
<Button>:
    background_normal: ''
<Label>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,0.59,0.36,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<TextInput>:
    hint_text: 'Nuwe nota'
    font_size: self.height / 4.5 if self.focus else self.height / 3
    background_normal: ''
    background_active: ''
    focus: True
    foreground_color: (0,0.61,0.36,1) if self.focus else (0.71,0.75,0.71,1)
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgb: (0,0,0,1)
        Line:
            points: self.pos[0] , self.pos[1], self.pos[0] + self.size[0], self.pos[1]
    size_hint_y: None
    height: Window.height / 6 if self.focus else Window.height / 12
<ChoiceBubble>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (160, 120)
    pos_hint: {'top': 0.2, 'right': 0.8}
    arrow_pos: 'top_left'
    BubbleButton:
        text: 'Save'
    BubbleButton:
        text: 'Encrypt..'
    BubbleButton:
        text: 'Delete'
        on_release: root.del_txt_input()
<Notation>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,0.43,0.37,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 0.8}
        size_hint: [0.8, None]
        height: Window.height / 15
    Button:
        text: 'Set'
        color: (0,0,0,1)
        pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 0.9}
        size_hint: [0.1, None]
        height: Window.height / 15

    Button:
        text: '+ Plus'
        color: (0,0,0,1)
        pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 1}
        size_hint: [0.1, None]
        height: Window.height / 15
        on_release: root.add_input()
    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: None
        size: Window.width, Window.height
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.92, 'right': 1}
        GridLayout:
            id: text_holder
            cols: 1
            pos_hint: {'top': 0.92, 'right': 1}
            padding: 4
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height

''')
class ChoiceBubble(Bubble):
    pass
class Notation(FloatLayout):
    which_txt = ObjectProperty(None)
    new_txt = ObjectProperty(None)
    def add_input(self):
        txt_hld = self.ids.text_holder
        if self.new_txt == None:
            self.new_txt = TextInput()
            txt_hld.add_widget(self.new_txt)
        else:
            self.new_txt.focus = False
            print(self.new_txt.focus)
            self.new_txt = TextInput(focus = True)
            print(self.new_txt.focus)
            txt_hld.add_widget(self.new_txt)
    def que_txt_input(self, instance):
        self.which_txt = instance
        print(instance)
    def del_txt_input(self):
        print(self.which_txt)

class theNoteApp(App):
    title = 'My Notes'
    def build(self):
        return Notation()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    theNoteApp().run()
```

#### **Desired Result:**

I want to start typing after adding a new `TextInput` and after clicking in another widget I want the `TextInput` to loose focus and fire a unfocus_on_touch event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem some time ago and I opened an [issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3863) at kivy's github page.
There is no solution yet, but there is a workaround.
You have to add these lines to your `TextInput` rule:

```
keyboard_mode: 'managed'
keyboard_on_key_down: self.show_keyboard()
```

After that, its working, but with the way you add the `widgets` you keep focus to all of them all the time, so you have to fix this independently.
The only focus that you need is at your `TextInput` rule, nowhere else..

Comment: Thanks that worked.  But  now the ```widgets``` are linked.  If I type in one and add another, the text I type also reflect in the previous ```widget```.  There is a myriad ways of solving this, by for instance identifying each new ```TextInput``` with indexed ```ids``` in a ```json``` storage file.  Do you know of a more elegant way to break the link?

Comment: @HermanHeunis Sorry I don't, because I used one `TextInput` at a time. :o(